# How can I invert a boolean value inside an SQL query?

Tags: android, sqlite, rx-java2, android-architecture-components

I am making an alarm app and I would to write a query that would toggle some alarm properties, here is my alarm class.

```
@Entity
data class Alarm(
    val label: String?,
    var isEnabled: Boolean,
    val ringTime: LocalTime,
    val occursOn: MutableSet<Day>,
    var isVibrationEnabled: Boolean,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int? = null
)
```

Here is my query that should invert vibration value

```
    @Query("UPDATE Alarm SET isVibrationEnabled = NOT isVibrationEnabled WHERE id = :alarmId")
    internal abstract fun toggleVibration(alarmId: Int): Completable
```

The app compiles fine, so it seems that the query is valid, however after I execute it, the value is not inverted and it stays the same

Comment: @forpas Boolean type

Comment: If there is no boolean type I would assume that there are 0 for false and 1 for true values

Comment: Does a row with id equal to the value you bind as `:alarmId` exist in the table?

Comment: Apparently that was the problem, like MikeT pointed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue is not the toggling, that works.

Rather that the issue is that the **WHERE clause** is not selecting a row (or the expected row) and thus that **the value passed as the parameter** when calling the **toggleVibration** function **is not the id** of an Alarm or the expected Alarm.

## Example

Consider the following example (in Java rather than Kotlin for convenience) :-

The AlarmEntity **Alarm.java**

```
public class Alarm {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;
    private String label;
    private boolean isEnabled;
    private boolean isVibrationEnabled;

    public Alarm() {

    }

    public Alarm(String label, boolean isEnabled, boolean isVibrationEnabled) {
        this.label = label;
        this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
        this.isVibrationEnabled = isVibrationEnabled;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isEnabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        isEnabled = enabled;
    }

    public boolean isVibrationEnabled() {
        return isVibrationEnabled;
    }

    public void setVibrationEnabled(boolean vibrationEnabled) {
        isVibrationEnabled = vibrationEnabled;
    }
}
```

- reduced set of columns for conveneience

**AlarmDao.java**

```
@Dao
public interface AlarmDao {

    @Insert
    long[] insertAlarm(Alarm... alarms);
    @Insert
    long insertAlarm(Alarm alarm);
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Alarm")
    List<Alarm> getAllAlarms();
    @Query("UPDATE Alarm SET isVibrationEnabled = NOT isVibrationEnabled WHERE id = :id")
    int toggleVibration(long id);
}
```

Code from an Activity to test :-

```
    alarmDao = mDB.getAlarmDao();
    // Add a copule of alarms
    alarmDao.insertAlarm(
            new Alarm("Alarm001",true,true),
            new Alarm("Alarm002",false,false)
    );
    // Get the Alarms and output them to the log
    List<Alarm> myalarms = alarmDao.getAllAlarms();
    for (Alarm a: myalarms) {
        Log.d("ALARMBEFORE","Label = " + a.getLabel() + " Enabaled = " + String.valueOf(a.isEnabled()) + " Vibration =  " + a.isVibrationEnabled());
    }
    //<<<<<<<<<< Toggle the first alarm >>>>>>>>>>
    alarmDao.toggleVibration(myalarms.get(0).getId());
    // Again get all the alarams and output them to the log
    myalarms = alarmDao.getAllAlarms();
    for (Alarm a: myalarms) {
        Log.d("ALARMAFTER","Label = " + a.getLabel() + " Enabaled = " + String.valueOf(a.isEnabled()) + " Vibration =  " + a.isVibrationEnabled());
    }
```

## Result

> ```
> 05-30 10:34:33.853 D/ALARMBEFORE: Label = Alarm001 Enabaled = true Vibration =  true
> 05-30 10:34:33.853 D/ALARMBEFORE: Label = Alarm002 Enabaled = false Vibration =  false
> 05-30 10:34:33.856 D/ALARMAFTER: Label = Alarm001 Enabaled = true Vibration =  false
> 05-30 10:34:33.856 D/ALARMAFTER: Label = Alarm002 Enabaled = false Vibration =  false
> ```

i.e. for Alarm001 the isVibrationEnabaled value has been toggled from true to **false**